# How to show custom keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard, android-edittext

I have EditText and I need to show my custom keyboard when user click this EditText. (I don't need to set this keyboard to defaut, just show it once with my editView) How to make it?

Answer (score 1):

In the xml, set the following

```
android:inputMethod="com.myapp.mykeyboard"
```

Comment: Yes.  You could set it at runtime via code too, but xml is easier.

Comment: Hm, it does not work. I have android 2.1+ and it says "android:inputMethod is deprecated: Use inputType instead", but i can't set custom keyboard to inputType.

Answer (score 1):

Make a layout for your keyboard and in your oncreate method do something like this

```
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
        // adjusting key regarding window sizes
        setKeys();
        setFrow();
        setSrow();
        setTrow();
        setForow();
        mEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.xEt);
        mEt.setOnTouchListener(this);
        mEt.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
        mEt1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et1);

        mEt1.setOnTouchListener(this);
        mEt1.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
        mEt.setOnClickListener(this);
        mEt1.setOnClickListener(this);
        mLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.xK1);
        mKLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.xKeyBoard);


@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if (v == mEt) {
        hideDefaultKeyboard();
        enableKeyboard();

    }
    if (v == mEt1) {
        hideDefaultKeyboard();
        enableKeyboard();

    }
    return true;
}
private void hideDefaultKeyboard() {
    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);

}
private void enableKeyboard() {

    mLayout.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.VISIBLE);
    mKLayout.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.VISIBLE);

}

// Disable customized keyboard
private void disableKeyboard() {
    mLayout.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.INVISIBLE);
    mKLayout.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.INVISIBLE);

}
```